# Печать String в формате BOLD

Tags: java

есть такая переменная

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так чтобы она выводилась жирным шрифтом?

Comment: выводилась куда?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q в эксель

Comment: вероятно, это зависит от того, как Вы выводите это в эксель

Answer (score 0):

"\u001B[1m" + text + "\u001B[2m"

Comment: данный вариант не подходит, правда я нашел решение этой задачи.
спасибо за содействие!